# How to fetch text and image from the server to the UI using Web-Push_php

Tags: javascript, php, service-worker

thanks alot for this web-push-php gist. I have been searching for how to implement web push notification since the beginning of the year. And I finally had yours. Thanks.

My problem is, I want to fetch text and image from the server to the user using web-push-php. But am facing error.

**Please I need Help or resolution**

**below is some portion of my client side and serverSide script for app.js, sw.js and sendMessage.php**

**app.js**

```js
fetch('/sendPushers/apk', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({endpoint: subscription.endpoint})
            })
```

**serviceWorker.js**

```js
var sendNotification = function(message, image) {
        // you could refresh a notification badge here with postMessage API
        self.refreshNotifications();

        var title   = "Steve Web Push example";

        return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body: message,
            icon: image
        });
    };

if (event.data) {
        var message = event.data.text();
        event.waitUntil(
            sendNotification(message['msg'],message['imageUrl'])
        );
    }
```

**sendMessage.php**

```
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $subscription = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    if (!isset($subscription['endpoint'])) {
      echo 'Error: not a subscription';
      return;
    }

    [
     'msg'=>(new \myPush\PushNotificationClass($subscription['endpoint']))
            ->PushNotificationActivity([]),
      'imageUrl'=>'userPhoto.png'
     ];
```

Comment: What **error** you are facing?

Comment: it does not fetch the userPhoto.png and the text from the server: nothing seems to happen or occur. I don't know whether my js script or php script that is not well formatted

Comment: you get nothing in console either?

Comment: What I got in the console was unexpected text (). So I replaced the event.data.text ()  with event.data.json (). But still it wasn't successful